# How to prevent PDF from opening on previously-viewed page?

Tags: pdf, okular

When I open a PDF it goes to the page that I last visited.

How can I prevent this so that whenever I open a PDF it goes to page 1?

I am using Document Viewer 3.4.0 and Okular 0.14.3.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmmm, sorry, now I'm at my PC, I stand corrected. I used to seek out the open last page option, but now somewhere along the line it has become default.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple, harmless workaround. Run in your shell:

```
alias okular="/usr/bin/okular -p 1"
```

Now okular will always open the doc on page 1.

To make this change permanent, add the alias to your shell's config file, such as `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not possible according to link below. I also did not find any setting in dconf-editor. Obviously, there is no such setting in application itself (Evince).

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+question/108052

Closest to what you need is probably just opening the document and then pressing **Ctrl+Home.**

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution for this:
Prevent okular to save the docdata

Step 1 : remove the Directory

```
rm -r ~/.local/share/okular/docdata
```

Step 2 : create a file preventing creation of the directory

```
touch ~/.local/share/okular/docdata
```

Now okular cannot save any docdata and will open on page 1 every time :-)