# How to prevent Okular from remembering last position in the file?

Tags: okular

How to make Okular not open the file at the last position? I couldn't find the option for it anywhere.

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/362071/how-to-prevent-pdf-from-opening-on-previously-viewed-page and possible reverse of: https://superuser.com/questions/301091/is-it-possible-to-configure-okular-to-open-a-given-file-at-the-position-where-it?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple, harmless workaround. Run in your shell:

```
alias okular="/usr/bin/okular -p 1"
```

Now okular will always open the doc on page 1.

To make this change permanent, add the alias to your shell's config file, such as `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`.